# Why Serilog Enrich WithThreadId throws error?

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

I have a problem with Serilog throwing `Unable to find a method called WithThreadId.`.

The version of Serilog I'm using is `Serilog.AspNetCore 6.1.0`. The way I register the logger is as follows:

```csharp
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((ctx, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration);
                    cfg.Enrich.WithProperty("EnvironmentName", ctx.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseKestrel()
                        .ConfigureServices((ctx, services) =>
                        {
                            services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(ctx.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
                        });
                });
    }
```

I have cascading appsettings.json, so in my `appsettings.json` for serilog I have:

```json
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId", "WithEnvironmentUserName" ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "STP.IM.DocumentPoolService"
    }
  }
}
```

In the following appsettings file I have:

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "System": "Information"
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.ms} {Level:u3}] {ThreadId} {MachineName} {EnvironmentUserName} {Message:lj} <s:{SourceContext}>{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

The full error I got is:

```
SERILOG SELFLOG: 2023-06-16T05:49:29.7322919Z Unable to find a method called WithThreadId. Candidate methods are:
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration WithEnvironmentName(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration WithMachineName(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration WithEnvironmentUserName(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration When(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, System.String, System.Action`1[Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration])
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration With(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, Serilog.Core.ILogEventEnricher)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration AtLevel(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration, System.Action`1[Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration], Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel, Serilog.Core.LoggingLevelSwitch)
Serilog.LoggerConfiguration FromLogContext(Serilog.Configuration.LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration)
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong? Can somebody give me a hint?

Comment: I guess you are missing the nuget for Thread? 
https://github.com/serilog/serilog-enrichers-thread